# Trouble with type conversion in constexpr template function

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I have a constexpr template function which converts radians to degrees, and a similar one which converts degrees to radians. However, when passing in a float into the function I get an error because of conversions saying I cannot convert a const float to a float. I solved this problem by creating a different function overload to accept const float as a parameter. Is there a way to make the function work with both types while still maintaining the ability to insert many variable types into the function?

```
template<typename T> constexpr float radToDeg(const T& rad)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<float>(rad) * static_cast<float>(180.f / PI);
}

constexpr float radToDeg(const float& rad)
{
    return rad * static_cast<float>(180.f / PI);
}
```

Comment: Do you know what `reinterpret_cast` is and what it's for?

Comment: constexpr float radToDeg(const float& rad) can't compile either because rad isn't actually a compile-time constant, it's a runtime parameter that's being passed in with the "const" modifier. That's not the same as an actual compile-time const value.

Comment: It compiles file and works. As far as reinterpret_cast yes, I understand what it does and know that it can't change const as const_cast is for that... However, I'm looking for some pro way to do this without overloading the function.

Comment: @BobBobby Okay, lets accept that you know what `reinterpret_cast` is for. Can you share with us the example where it would be needed in this case?

Comment: It won't compile if I passed in PI as a regular const float variable. It would once I defined PI as a constexpr as well. you should be aware of the conditions needed to compile your code.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't what [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) is for.

`template<typename T> constexpr float radToDeg(const T& rad)
{
    return static_cast<float>(rad) * static_cast<float>(180.f / PI);
}`